# Is there any way to apply a pose to a mesh and be able to remove the armature and keep the pose?

Tags: modeling, armature

Im trying to import a model into the oculus home but when i do the character isnt posed but is in blender. idk if theres a way to fix this so oculus can read the armature pose or that i can fully apply all of the pose to the mesh

Answer (score 1):

Yes: apply the mesh's armature modifier, then you can delete the armature. :)

Note: save backups as this is permanent

Comment: thank you! i didnt think the solution would be that easy